# How to run a command only if sed replace strings

Tags: sed

I want to enable multiverse repository in Ubuntu by a command line.

```
sed -i "/^# deb.*multiverse/ s/^# //" /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update
```

This command will run `apt-get update` every time, but it's necessary only when `sed` comments the line out.

Is there easy way to detect if `sed` replaces strings and run a command depending on that result?

Comment: You can try exiting with a custom exit code and check for it, if you have GNU sed.

Comment: You mean its only necessary when `sed` uncomments the line?

Comment: @muru I'm using `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`. If I need some customization for it, I'll stick with current way. I seems too difficult and complex for just a small change.

Comment: @mikeserv yes, it is.

Comment: Or `grep -q '^# deb.*multiverse' /etc/apt/sources.list && sed blah blah && apt-get update`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do here is just to `grep` for the commented line first:

```
grep -q '^# deb.*multiverse' /etc/apt/sources.list &&
  sed -i '/^# deb.*multiverse/ s/^# //' /etc/apt/sources.list &&
  apt-get update
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this question already has an answer, but I was curious to see if I could come up with a sed-only answer (without using grep as in the accepted answer). As it turns out, it seems possible :

```
sed -ni '/^# deb.*multiverse/{;h;s/^# //;};p;${;g;/^#/!q1;}' /etc/apt/sources.list
  && apt-get update
```

(Of course, everything must be on the same line, but I wanted everything to be visible without having to scroll horizontally.)

**Explanation :**

- Look for the pattern (`/^# deb.*multiverse/`)
- If found :

  - Hold the line in the hold buffer (`h`)
  - Do the uncommenting (`s/^# //`)
- Print the line
- On the last line only (`$`)

  - Copy the line held in the hold buffer into the pattern buffer (`g`)
  - Test if the hold buffer begins with a comment sign (it would be empty if no replacement occured) (`/^#/`)
  - If we don't have a match, exit with code `1` to signal no replacement has been made (`!q1`) (else it exits normally with code `0`)

Now I know this answer is really not as clear as simply using grep, but I was interested in the challenge and came up with this, so I thought I'd share.

Comment: Well done, I was trying this and never got anywhere - didn't think of using the hold buffer. I would note that this will only work on GNU `sed` (or another with the extension to quit with an exit code) though in case someone tries it on a different system.

Answer (score 3):

```
{   sed -i '/^# \(deb.*multiv.*\)/h;s//\1/p
        $x;s//apt-get update/w /dev/fd/2' file
}   2>&1 >/dev/null | sh -v
```

That command will only output the line `apt-get update` fed to `sh` over a pipe if it does at least one replacement while reading `file`.

Answer (score 1):

sed doesn't have variables. There's the `t` command that jumps to a label after a successful `s///`, and the `q` command takes an exit code. But since you're rewriting the file, you can't exit after the substitution, you have to read the whole file first.

I'd switch to another language. perl works here: newlines for readability

```
perl -i -pe '
    BEGIN {$x=1} 
    if (/^# deb.*multiverse/) {s/^# //; $x=0}
    END {exit $x}
' /etc/apt/sources.list &&
apt-get update
```

Comment: sed has exactly one variable - the hold buffer ;-)

Comment: man, I have a love-hate relationship with sed.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Actually, with `H`, you can append multiple lines to the hold buffer. You have therefore an unlimited supply of variables, provided you keep track of which line you want. Now, if you do this, comment the hell out of your script, else it will look like assembly : a lot of statements that make sense individually, but no idea whatsoever as to what it does once combined. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is with `ed`, taking advantage of a built-in feature: *if no substitution is made on the addressed lines, it's considered as an error; if the standard input is a regular file,* `ed` *shall terminate with a non-zero exit status*.
You could use *herestring*:

```
ed -s /etc/apt/sources.list <<< $',s/^# \\(deb.*multiverse\\)/\\1/\nw\n!apt-get update\nq'
```

or *heredoc*:

```
ed -s /etc/apt/sources.list <<IN
,s/^# \(deb.*multiverse\)/\1/
w
!apt-get update
q
IN
```

to pass the following commands to `ed`:

```
,s/^# \(deb.*multiverse\)/\1/      replace pattern with something 
w                                  write changes to file
!apt-get update                    run this command in shell
q                                  quit editor
```

However, if no match is found that means no `s`ubstitution is made, so `ed` bombs out (the only output is a question mark `?` meaning `error`<sup>1</sup>) and as a result the subcommands on subsequent lines are not executed. To test it, you could actually replace `apt-get update` with another command like `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` or `echo DONE`.

---

1:
If the question mark bothers you, just redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` e.g.:

```
ed -s /etc/apt/sources.list 2>/dev/null <<....
```